# jquery selector for td click event for child table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implemement a click event listener for the child table (nested within parent table). Can someone please help me on what i am doing wrong? the below is not working

```
<table id="MAIN_TABLE" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped dataTable no-footer" style="font-size: 14px; width: 1167px;" role="grid" aria-describedby="Hq_PendingTable_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row"><th>...</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd shown">
            <td class="details-control sorting_1"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td>1</td>                
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9">
                <div id="DivTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <table id="DIV_TABLE" class="dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
                                <thead>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="subDetails"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
```

I need to implement click event on DIV_TABLE first td. I am doing as below which doesnt work. Please suggest the correct way

```
$('#MAIN_TABLE #DIV_TABLE tbody').on('click', 'td.subDetails', function () {
```

Comment: Is this table added dynamically? Also, there's no need to include the first ID selector and drill down - ID's are unique, so `#DIV_TABLE` should be good enough

Comment: Please provide more context, including where your JavaScript is on the page

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/m5revo19/1/

Comment: Are you sure you have only one element on the page with `id="DIV_TABLE"`?

Comment: thanks Barmar, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle here (simplifying your tables somewhat just for an example):
http://jsfiddle.net/juywt3aL/5/

Instead of calling the table id, I just had it call the `<td>`'s class:

```
$('td.subDetails').on('click', function () {
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
});
```

I think that should do what you need it to.